# Installing pymongo in Azure python flask app

Tags: azure, pymongo

I have a python flask app that inserts data to mongo cloud and the way it does it is using pymongo module.

My question is how do I install pymongo in azure cloud so I can run the flask app in azure

Comment: Can you list what you have tried and the error or issue you are experiencing?

Answer (score 0):

You question is quite broad, but a good place to start is [Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-python?tabs=bash).

Include pymongo in your [requirements.txt](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files) file and include the line

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

as documented on that page to install pymongo.